# mysql self join with where

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table  name categories

having  two fields

```
cat_id category_id  
199     103
172     122
172     112
112     176
```

I want an output if  cat_id = 172

```
is 122, 112, 176.
```

i have wrote this query

```
SELECT f.`category_id` FROM `following_follower_categories` f , 
`following_follower_categories` AS b 
 WHERE  f.`follower_category_id` = `b`.`category_id` 
       AND f.follower_category_id  = 172
```

it is showing empty

Anybody help me out

Comment: I can not see the column `follower_category_id` in your table description?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a `union all` query:

```
select c.category_id
from categories
where cat_id = 172
union all
select c1.category_id
from categories c join
     categories c1
     on c1.cat_id = c.category_id
where c.cat_id = 172;
```

Note that this follows the naming conventions in your text and sample data, where the names don't match the sample query.

Comment: With union all it will include the duplicates from the first select and second one. It should be union without "ALL"

Comment: @DoubleM . . . I suspect that such duplicates would indicate a cycle in the hierarchical structure of the data.  Such cycles are not suggested in the question.  If it is a possibility, then the OP should definitely use `union` rather than `union all`.  However, `union` incurs extra overhead so it should only be used when necessary.

Answer (score 0):

think you have a misstake in the where cluse. It must be:

```
SELECT f.`category_id` FROM `following_follower_categories` f , 
`following_follower_categories` AS b 
 WHERE  f.`follower_category_id` = `b`.`category_id` 
       AND f.category_id  = 172
```

Answer (score 0):

another solution using sub-query method

```
SELECT category_id
FROM following_follower_categories
WHERE cat_id=172 or cat_id in (
                               SELECT category_id 
                               FROM following_follower_categories  
                               WHERE cat_id=172
                               )
```

typically joins are faster than sub-queries and sub-queries are faster than operators statements i.e. unions

ill see if i can come up with a join solution :D